# Arduino MEGA Timer Help

Tags: arduino-mega

Nick Gammon posted some code to setup a counter on an Arduino UNO using timer2 to generate a 38KHZ signal, and I've used it on several IR projects.

On my current project, I'm using FreeRTOS for the Arduino, and the source says it uses timers 0-3 for its own kernel operation, so the timer code obviously will interfere with the RTOS.

I'm using an Arduino MEGA for this project, and AFAICT it also has a timer4 and timer5. Unfortunately, my programming ability for the ATMel products is lacking at that level, so I'm looking for some help to create a timer that will generate a 38KHZ output using timer4 or timer5 of the MEGA 2560 on any output pin. Interrupts shouldn't be used because it would also probably cause issues with RTOS.

BTW, on the Arduino MEGA, you can do a context switch between tasks in less that 200usec, and be able to determine what task YOU want to execute next.

Comment: Can you show me where I can read that freertos uses timers 0-3? In my opinion it does not use any of those timers.

Comment: For the life of me, I can't find what I found before.....I did find some example code that setup the watchdog timer to generate the basic tick function time, and the code allows using almost any of the HW timers. I did see that some of the docs posted say that the RTOS timers don't depend on any HW, but it also says that the SW timers don't use any processor time?? That doesn't make sense. The lack of documentation in this area may show that no HW is indeed used, especially because the RTOS will run on almost any Arduino, and the timers are quite different in capability.

Comment: The file that has the timer stuff is; \avrfreertos-master\avrfreertos-master\freeRTOS10xx\include\FreeRTOSBoardDefs.h

Comment: The watchdog timer is recommended, but I see that for the arduino mega 2560 the timer3 is used in this one: https://github.com/feilipu/avrfreertos/blob/master/freeRTOS10xx/include/FreeRTOSBoardDefs.h That is okay, since timer0, timer1 and timer2 are not used by freertos. The library manager in the arduino ide uses a mini version of freertos, and that one uses the watchdog timer: https://github.com/feilipu/Arduino_FreeRTOS_Library/blob/596a743509309121afcf7fa95c4d17d6d7fdd7ce/src/FreeRTOSVariant.h Why did you choose the larger version of freertos?

Comment: I just downloaded the version that the IDE showed. I didn't know there was another, smalled version. The size of the code isn't important to the project, as there will be only 3 tasks running that are all process dependant, but just scan while running in a state machine. They'll all run at the same priority, and at each exit from each state in the loop they're in, they will yield to the next task. ALL of them will always be in the ready state. Originally, I setup the code to chage their own priority to match all the rest, and then raise the priority of the next task to run.

Comment: Then that task lowers its prority and then raises the priorty of the next task to run. I set this up with dummy tasks to measure the context switch times, and couldn't tell any difference between the two techniques. As I stated above, the context switch time was less than 200usec. I need to do this because the original code ran in separate Arduino modules, and monitors IR detectors setup in a quadrature configuration with less than 0.030" separating them.

Comment: So, the state machines need to be very responsive, and the 200usec context switch will minimize any latency in the detection because the state machine stays in a switch statement loop, and the execution time is very fast, actually many times faster than needed for detection. So, the code should function with minimal changes. AFAICT, the only real difference would be just to do the context switch right before the break statement for each case.

Comment: I installed the "FreeRTOS by Richard Barry" from the library manager and I got the mini version. I think you don't need a rtos, you can put three finite state machines in the loop and remove all delays and use interrupts for the ir detectors. An interrupt itself uses a few microseconds in a avr microcontroller: https://gammon.com.au/interrupts The code inside an interrupt takes often more microseconds, because a single digitalread uses about 4 microseconds.

Comment: The state machine is complex, and with 2 running in each task, having 6 total machines interacting would be a ZOO trying to troubkeshoot. I really don't want to start all over. Currently the code works fine, but if I run into performance issues, I'll reconsider. BTW, the code that Nick wrote for the 38KHZ output works just fine in the RTOS, but it outpouts on data pin 10 on the MEGA instead of data pin 11 on the UNO. So, the project continues to its next phase.

Comment: I think we both learned from this. I have created an answer (with my opinion). I have used freertos, and it is working well. However, I think that the disadvantages are larger than the benefits.

Answer (score 0):

Using a pre-emptive Real Time Operating System on a Arduino board with a AVR microcontroller (Arduino Uno, Leonardo, Mega 2560) is an academic exercise.

The FreeRTOS is reliable, and for someone that is used to write multitasking code, it can be useful.
In my opinion, the FreeRTOS does not match with the simple AVR Arduino boards:

- Not enough ram memory.
  Every task gets its own stack. 
  The ram memory is limited on a AVR board. That means that every
  task should be written very careful to limit the stack usage.
- Not enough ram when the fun is about to start.
  When there are a few tasks and perhaps a few interrupt routines,
  then a number of buffers and message queues are needed. 
  There is not enough ram memory for that.
- The Arduino was not developed with a multitasking system in mind.
  The Arduino libraries are not suitable for that. 
  Some functions wait 
  for something (Serial.parseInt, Wire.requestFrom,
  Wire.endTransmission)
  and that makes a RTOS work worse than expected.
- The FreeRTOS is large, it requires memory and cpu time.

Without FreeRTOS, some known techniques are very efficient for the AVR Arduino boards:

- A Finite State Machine uses very little ram memory.
  A Finite State Machine without `delay()` 
  that uses `millis()` can be very responsive.
- Avoiding interrupt routines.
  It is often possible to avoid interrupt routines.
  Reading buttons can often be done by polling the buttons 
  in the `loop()`.
- Avoiding the String object and moving text into PROGMEM 
  can be used
  to have enough memory for a more complex and reliable sketch.

At this moment the "FreeRTOS by Richard Barry" is in the Library Manager. It is a smaller version of FreeRTOS and it only uses the WatchDog timer. It has no conflict with Arduino libraries.

A larger FreeRTOS version and many examples can be found at https://github.com/feilipu/avrfreertos
Not every version of FreeRTOS uses the WatchDog timer. Look for the file `FreeRTOSBoardDefs.h` to see which timer is used for your specific Arduino board.

crusader27529, I don't see a problem to remove the FreeRTOS and call the three tasks sequencially.

```
void loop() {
  task1();
  task2();
  task3();
}
```

Comment: The nature of the tasks is that they never terminate, but continuously monitor multiple IR sensors that are time critical, all run in multiple state machines. Using RTOS, I can use the YIELD function to force the running task into a state that allows the next task to run. Since all the tasks are the same priority, it results is a cooperative task switching operation with extremely low context switching overhead. AAMOF, I can switch sequentially among 4 tasks in sequence in less than 200usec. That actually works out tf about 50usec per task context switch, with minimal changes to the old code.

Comment: @crusader27529 I understand now, you stay in the finite state machine and perform a yield to the other ones. Without a RTOS, the loop() runs over and over again and rushes through the finite state machines. That is a different approach.